# Problems with creating Action Bar "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.Item"

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-actionbar

I'm getting the following error with my Android Application: http://goo.gl/JYva5p + http://goo.gl/UuhepQ (Couldn't fit it all onto one, and Eclipse won't let me copy the error message)

Here's my code:

```
package com.jamco.apps.mikey;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Random;

import zh.wang.android.apis.yweathergetter4a.WeatherInfo;
import zh.wang.android.apis.yweathergetter4a.YahooWeather;
import zh.wang.android.apis.yweathergetter4a.YahooWeather.SEARCH_MODE;
import zh.wang.android.apis.yweathergetter4a.YahooWeatherInfoListener;

import com.jamco.apps.mikey.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Mikey extends Activity implements RecognitionListener, OnClickListener, TextToSpeech.OnInitListener, YahooWeatherInfoListener {

protected static final int REQUEST_OK = 1;
private ImageButton btn;
private static TextToSpeech tts;
private Button txt;
private Button txt2;
private ArrayList<String> thingsYouSaid = new ArrayList<String>();
private Integer numberOfThingsSaid = 0;

private Calendar c;
private String loc;

private Boolean askingQuestion = false;
private String questionResult = "";
private String question;
volatile Boolean waitingToSpeak = false;

private YahooWeather mYahooWeather = YahooWeather.getInstance();

private String name = "";

HashMap<String, String> conversation = new HashMap<String, String>();

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    //Don't forget to shutdown tts!
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mikey);

    btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    txt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    txt2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    tts.setPitch(2f);
    tts.setSpeechRate(3f);

    txt2.setVisibility(1);
    txt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");
            try {
                startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_OK);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error initializing speech to text engine.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode==REQUEST_OK  && resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
            if (!askingQuestion) {
                numberOfThingsSaid += 1;
                ArrayList<String> youJustSaid = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                txt.setText("You said: \n" + youJustSaid.get(0));
                thingsYouSaid.add(youJustSaid.get(0));
                think();
            } else {

            }
        }
    }

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

        int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
        } else {
            btn.setEnabled(true);
        }

    } else {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
    }
}

@Override
public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
    //TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onEndOfSpeech() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onError(int error) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onResults(Bundle results) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void speak(String speech) {
    if (!askingQuestion) {
        if (!tts.isSpeaking()) {
            txt2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tts.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            txt2.setText("I said: \n" + speech);
        } else {
            waitingToSpeak = true;
            while (waitingToSpeak){
                if (!tts.isSpeaking()) {
                    waitingToSpeak = false;
                }
            }
            speak(speech);
        }
    } else {
        waitingToSpeak = true;
        while (waitingToSpeak){
            if (!askingQuestion) {
                waitingToSpeak = false;
            }
        }
        speak(speech);
    }
}

private void think() {
    if (last().contains("hello") || last().contains("hi")) {
        switch (randInt(0, 2)) {
            case 0:
                speak("Hi");
                break;
            case 1:
                speak("Hello");
                break;
            case 2:
                speak(last());
                break;
        }
    } else if (last().contains("time") && (last().contains("what") || last().contains("tell")) && !last().contains("in")) {
        c = Calendar.getInstance();
        speak("The time is currently " + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " minutes past " + c.get(Calendar.HOUR) + " and " + c.get(Calendar.SECOND) + " seconds.");
    } else if (last().contains("time") && (last().contains("what") || last().contains("tell")) && last().contains("in")) {
        //  Tell time in <Place>
    } else if (last().contains("weather") && last().contains("what") && (!last().contains("in") || !last().contains("at"))) {
        mYahooWeather.setSearchMode(SEARCH_MODE.GPS);
        mYahooWeather.queryYahooWeatherByGPS(getApplicationContext(), this);
    } else if (last().contains("weather") && last().contains("what") && (last().contains("in") || last().contains("at"))) {
        loc = last().substring(last().lastIndexOf("in"), last().length());
        mYahooWeather.setSearchMode(SEARCH_MODE.PLACE_NAME);
        mYahooWeather.queryYahooWeatherByPlaceName(getApplicationContext(), loc, this);
    } else if (last().contains("*") || last().contains("-") || last().contains("+") || last().contains("plus") || last().contains("root") || last().contains("cubed") || last().contains("squared") || last().contains("times") || last().contains("multiplied") || last().contains("divided") || last().contains("add") || last().contains("subtract") || last().contains("minus") || last().contains("takeaway") || last().contains("added") || last().contains("power")) {
        //It's a math sum!
        speak("Sorry, I can't do maths yet.");

        //if (last().contains("plus") || last().contains("add") || last().contains("added") || last().contains("+")) {
        //  if (last().contains("plus") || last().contains("add") || last().contains("+")) {
        //      
        //  }
        //}
    } else if (last().contains("what") || last().contains("your") || last().contains("name")) {
        if (name == "") {
            askingQuestion = true;
            speak("Hello " + askQuestion("My name is Mikey. \n What's your name?"));
            btn.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            speak("My name is Mikey. \n Your name is " + name);
        }

    } else if (last().contains("what") || last().contains("my") || last().contains("name")) {
        if (name == "") {
            speak("Hello " + askQuestion("I don't know your name. \n What is your name?"));
        }
    }
}

public String askQuestion(String msg) {
    btn.setEnabled(false);
    tts.speak(msg, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    conversation.put(msg, "");
    question = msg;
    String string = "";
    return string;
}

public void questionResult(String result) {
    conversation.put(question, result);
}

public String last() {
    return thingsYouSaid.get(numberOfThingsSaid - 1).toLowerCase(Locale.UK);
}

public static int randInt(int min, int max) {

//  Usually this can be a field rather than a method variable
    Random rand = new Random();

//  nextInt is normally exclusive of the top value,
//  so add 1 to make it inclusive
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

    return randomNum;
}

@Override
public void gotWeatherInfo(WeatherInfo weatherInfo) {
    speak("The weather is currently " + weatherInfo.getCurrentText() + " in " + weatherInfo.getLocationCity() +", with a temperature of around " + weatherInfo.getCurrentTempC() + " degrees centigrade.");
}

public void repeatLast() {
    speak("I said, " + thingsYouSaid.get(numberOfThingsSaid - 2).toLowerCase(Locale.UK));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mikey, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
}
```

(sorry for bad formatting)

Here's my Activity XML:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Mikey"
android:configChanges="orientation"
android:screenOrientation="portrait">

<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<Item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:showAsAction="never" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
    android:background="@drawable/box1"
    android:maxWidth="240dp"
    android:text="Click the Microphone and speak!"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
    android:background="@drawable/box2"
    android:maxWidth="240dp"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My problem is I, in short, I can't add items to the action bar! The compiler doesn't know what 'Item' is in the XML and I can't work out why (this is what I can tell, I may be wrong). All the tutorials I've followed tell me the action bar is included in the theme 'Holo' in API version 11 or later, which I've used for my application.

If you need some more info, please ask me for it.

**Thanks in advance!**

EDIT: Also, I've included 'android-support-v4.jar' as a library in my application following the official Android Dev. Tutorial for action bars, although, other sites don't tell me to do this.

Comment: Items to be added in the actionbar need to be in the res/menu directory where you create a menu xml. In your java file you override onCreateOptionsMenu(...) you then make sure you inflate a your menu xml there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your ActionBar menu's are not a part of your Activity layout. delete <Item.../> in layout and

declare

```
<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<Item 
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:showAsAction="never" />
```

in the menu some thing like this...

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
</menu>
```

create an xml file in res/menu folder with the name main.xml (actually it can be any name) and write this code.

and add this code in your `Activity`

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

and to handle click event of this settings menu, add below code in your Activity...

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        // Settings in ActionBar clicked
        // start your Activity here
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! :) Oh, and one last question, I'm now trying to open a different activity from a button in the action bar, here's my code so far: http://goo.gl/WNzdkz but, how do I actually open another activity once I've detected a click?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain it right, but the problem I'm having is how do I actually go about starting the Settings Activity?

Comment: so you want to startActivity when user clicks on settings menu?

Comment: Yes, but I'm just unsure how to call `startActivityForResult()` correctly.

Comment: see simple tutorial here... http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html

Comment: OK, now that's working, I have another problem... there's no errors, but now when I start the application there's no sign of an action menu, no overflow button, and pressing the Hardware Menu button does nothing too.

Answer (score 0):

Items to be added in the actionbar need to be in the res/menu directory where you create a menu xml (let's say you call it `my_menu.xml`). In your java file you override `onCreateOptionsMenu(...)` you then make sure you inflate a your menu xml there.

Something like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,
                                MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Make sure you `my_menu.xml` looks something like this:

```
<menu 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```